# Cannot assign task to user

Tags: workflow, tasks

I am attempting to create a task in my state machine workflow on SP2010.

```
theTaskID = Guid.NewGuid();
theTask.AssignedTo = "domain\\dave.lozzi";
theTask.Title = "Application";
theTask.Description = "The application requires your review";
theTask.TaskType = 0;
```

Pretty simple right? When I run the workflow the task gets created. If I change the AssignedTo to anyone else (I tried 3 other accounts), the task gets created but no one is assigned. Each user is in the Members group and has Contribute permission to the site.

I even logged in as one of the other users, updated the code to match my new user name, and that still didn't work.

I can update the task manually and assign it there to the account I need to, and I can do this under my account and another account. I don't think it's a permissions issue...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

I used the EnsureUser method which fixed it.

```
        SPUser usr = workflowProperties.Web.EnsureUser("domain\\sptest01");
        theTask.AssignedTo = usr.LoginName;
```